# How to run MATLAB script from Atom editor

Tags: bash, matlab, atom-editor

I'm trying to run MATLAB scripts from the Atom editor but it is throwing me an error. How to I configure the run options and create a profile? I'm not acquainted with bash scripting.

The error that I'm getting is shown below:

[image]

One option is to configure run options and create a profile using the [script](https://atom.io/packages/script) package.

In the linux terminal, the following command runs my MATLAB file:

```
matlab9 -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('/home/shihab/Desktop/paper2/uqlab/XYZ.m');exit;"
```

In order to configure the run options and create a profile, script asks me the following options:

[image]

I've tried some options but it still didn't work.
Any idea on how can I run the script?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I've added a picture with the error in my original question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that all I had to do what to simply add MATLAB to the PATH variable.

I ran the following command:

```
export PATH="$PATH":/usr/local/MATLAB/R2019a/bin
```

and restarted Atom. Now it is able to run MATLAB with script using the shortcut key ctrl+shift+b.